# 's' prefix for list in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Already did some searches on SO and looked on the python 3 documentation for str.split() and list()**

Why does python prefix a list object with `s` when it prints to my terminal from a `.py` script, but not when I'm in the python shell?

For example, if I make a short python program and execute it from the command line,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
my_path="/data/user"
print(my_path.strip().split("/"))
```

it outputs this: `s['', 'data', 'user']`

However, if I open the python shell and execute the same code, the `s` prefix disappears. Why is this, and can anyone link a resource to explain what is going on?

```
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.1.0 (64-bit)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
>>> my_path = "/data/user"
>>> print(my_path.strip().split("/"))
['', 'data', 'user']
```

Comment: This is not expected behavior. There is no `s` prefix in Python, not for lists nor anything else. What happens if you `print()` some other object?

Comment: That output isn't valid Python syntax like `r'string'` or `u'string'` are; `s[...]` would be indexing into a variable called `s`; I can't reproduce it with Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu here. It feels like a shell, encoding or environment thing rather than a Python thing to me... but I can't think what would do that. Are you using Bash or something else, and do you have any customisations for it - for your prompt, or anything else?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this `s` on my CentOS with python 3.5.0. Very strange! Could you print 2 time `print(my_path.strip().split("/")); print(my_path.strip().split("/"))` to see what would happen?

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry to waste your time, everyone!**

I realized that I was executing this script from a `unittest` class and that the `s` character is printed upon execution of the `setup()` method. No problems now, thank you.